# Proving existence of a global maximum

Tags: real-analysis

I am given a function $f$ that is continuous and periodic with period $p$. The domain of the function is entire real numbers. I have to prove that the function has a global maximum.

Attempt:
First, I proved that a continuous function that is bounded by two elements on its domain must have a maximum.

Question:

Is it correct to now just write that since $f$ is periodic, if I consider the function in an interval $[0,p]$, then the function will just be repeated outside the interval and since I have proved that there is a maximum in that interval, it will also be the global maximum? What I am confused about is: the question asks me to prove existence of a global maximum. But if the function is repeating with period $p$, there are many such maxima. But isn't global maximum unique? What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: A global maxima is unique but can be reached by multiple points. Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$, it is $2\pi$-periodic and has a global maxima of $1$ but you reach this global maxima for an infinite amount of points of the form ${\pi\over 2}+2k\pi, k\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From the comments above by @Furrane.*

---

The global maximum is unique but it can be attained by multiple points. Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$. It is $2\pi$-periodic and has a global maximum equal to $1$. But, this maximum is attained by an infinite number of points, namely every point of the form $\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 k \pi$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.